# boost check if the type belong to a list of given types

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I have the following problem. In the template, I want to check if the type is one of the given types.

Code description:

```
tempalte <typename T>
class foo
{
public:
//BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(T is one of int, long, long long, double ....);
//boost::is_scalar doesn't fill my requirements since I need 
//to provide my own list of types
};
```

I know how to do it using the template specification, but this way is tedious.

```
   template <typename T>
    class ValidateType
    {
        static const bool valid = false;
    };

    template <>
    class ValidateType<int>
    {
        static const bool valid = true;
    }

    //repeat for every wanted type
```

Is there elegant way?

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
#include <boost/mpl/set.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/assert.hpp>

typedef boost::mpl::set<int, long, long long, double, ...> allowed_types;
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((boost::mpl::has_key<allowed_types, int>));  // Compiles
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((boost::mpl::has_key<allowed_types, char>)); // Causes compile-time error
```

Comment: Hello, how can I extend the list of allowed_types for example allowing vector<allowed_types> in a single assert statement ?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Supposing I want to allow `bool`, `std::string` and `int` as well as `std::vector<bool>`, `std::vector<std::string>`, `std::vector<int>` without explicitely mentioning within the `mpl::set` their vector flavour.

Comment: I moved on from C++, so my knowledge might be a bit rusty. Having said that, I think it should be possible to write a `drop_vector` metafunction which maps `T -> T` and `vector<T>  ->  T`. In that case, you can query for `drop_vector<T>::type` in `allowed_types`. If you need help with that (or if I promised too much), it's best to open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [MPL `vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/vector.html) (which is a vector of *types*) with the [`contains`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/contains.html) algorithm:

```
typedef vector<int, long, long long, double> types;
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT(( contains<types, T> ));
```

Comment: it's not working, "typedef boost::mpl::vector<int, long, long long, double> types;
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT(( contains<types, char> )); " compilation passes